# Yii User Registration returns hashed password back to user on an error?

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am authenticating with the database an I have the problem whereby if an email address is of the incorrect format, the same page is returned to the user with the errors on the page. Problem is that the Password still gets hashed and is added to the returned form.

my controller::actionRegister():

```
$model = new User('register');
        if (isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            $model->password = crypt($model->password, $model->blowfishSalt());
            if ($model->save())
            {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }   
        $this->render('register', array('model'=>$model));
```

my view: register.php

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I make sure that using the 'Register' Scenario the password is not returned to the form and / or that the password does not get hashed until all other errors have vanquished. As the hash takes some time?

Comment: You can define notHashedPassword property in the model, and in beforeSave() method do something like this `$this->password = crypt($model->notHashedPassword, $model->blowfishSalt());`
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/277/model-password-confirmation-field

Answer (score 0):

lysenkobv's comment is correct or you can change your code to this, use validate and don't modify the password till after validation:

```
if (isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        if ($model->validate())
        {
            $model->password = crypt($model->password, $model->blowfishSalt());
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        } else {
            //if you want password to clear so they have to retype it
            $model->password = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = new User('register');
    if (isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
        $password = $model->password;
        $model->password = crypt($model->password, $model->blowfishSalt());
        if ($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        else {
            $model->password = $password;
        }
    }   
    $this->render('register', array('model'=>$model));
```